# counting lines from file not using getline()

Tags: c++

I want to get some data from file and put it to variables. But before, I don't know the length of this file. File looks like:

```
 1 12 4
 2 14 5
 3 26 6
 . .. .
```

That's why I want to get a number of lines to know, how much variables I need to create in loop. In this code I created 3 variables (a,b,c) to try. The problem is that after the end of program a,b,c are just random numbers instead of 1, 12 and 4.
I noticed that if I put this:

> file >> a >> b >> c;

before while loop it works, but I need number of lines earlier.
So how to count lines not using `getline()` ?

```
int a, b, c;
fstream file;
file.open("abc.txt",ios::in);

if (file.good() == true)
{
    int lines_amount=0;
    string test; 



    while (getline(file,test))
    {
        lines_amount++;
    }
    file >> a >> b >> c;

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: use a `vector` inside the loop then you don't need to know the line count up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
while (getline(file,test))
{
      lines_amount++;
}
```

the `while` loop stops only after everything from the file has been read. The line

```
file >> a >> b >> c;
```

does not read anything into `a`, `b`, or `c`. The values of those variables are some random values that you get since they have not been initialized before.

Initialize them to something like:

```
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30;
```

and you will notice that:

1. If you use a pre-C++11 compiler, the values of those variable remain unchanged.
2. If you use a C++11 or later compiler, the values of those variables will be set to 0.

To be able to read the numbers from the start of the file, rewind it to the top. You can use `std::ifstream::seekg` for that. You have to clear its `eofbit` first though.

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(std::ifstream::beg);
```

Comment: Thanks :) But i have a question, it started working only after i added file.clear();  before file.seekg(0); . Do you know why ? I'm just curious :)

Comment: When the `while` loop stops, `file` is in a state of `eofbit`. You need to clear that before you can read from it. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good for further info.

Comment: "*you will notice that the values of those variable remain unchanged*" - that is not true starting in C++11. If `operator>>` fails to read a value, 0 is written to the output variable.

Answer (score 2):

What about rewinding the file indicator?

```
file.seekg(std::ifstream::beg);
```

In the previous `while` loop, the whole file has already been read, so there's nothing left for the next read, and `a`, `b` and `c` remain untouched. After this code, the file indicator is reset to the beginning of the file, so you're able to read from start again.

You may need to add `file.clear()` before calling `seekg()` to clear any flags that are already set, to prevent further operations from failing. Most of them don't do anything if a bad flag is set. In your case, when attempting to read more, the `operator >> ()` function finds a bad flag (`std::ios_base::iostate::eofbit`) and stops. [Further Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good)

Comment: But i have similar question for you :) Why it didn't work unless i added file.clear(); before file.seekg(0) ?

Comment: @db14 I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> That's why i want to get a number of lines to know, how much variables i need to create in loop.

You don't need to know the number of lines beforehand. Use a `std::vector` to store the values, and let it grow dynamically as you add values into it. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct values {
    int a, b, c;
};

std::vector<values> data;
std::ifstream file("abc.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        values v;
        if (iss >> v.a >> v.b >> v.c) {
            data.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    // use data as needed...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct values {
    int a, b, c;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, values &v) {
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(in, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (!(iss >> v.a >> v.b >> v.c)) {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return in;
}

std::vector<values> data;
ifstream file("abc.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<values>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<values>(),
        std::back_inserter(data));
    file.close();
    // use data as needed...
}
```